# Is there a connection between "Having a chip on one's shoulder" and "Knock it off"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin

After reading the Wikipedia article I was wondering about a possible connection between these two idioms.

Quoted from [Wikipedia: Chip on shoulder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_shoulder)

> This idiom traces its roots back to a custom that was known in North America since the early 19th century. The New York newspaper Long Island Telegraph reported on 20 May 1830 "when two churlish boys were determined to fight, a chip [of wood] would be placed on the shoulder of one, and the other demanded to **knock it off** at his peril".
>
> A similar notion is mentioned in the issue of the Onondaga Standard of Syracuse, New York on 8 December 1830: "'He waylay me', said I, 'the mean sneaking fellow — I am only afraid that he will sue me for damages. Oh! if I only could get him to **knock a chip off my shoulder**, and so get round the law, I would give him one of the soundest thrashings he ever had'."
>
> Some time later in 1855, the phrase "chip on his shoulder" appeared in the Weekly Oregonian, stating "Leland, in his last issue, struts out with a **chip on his shoulder**, and dares Bush to **knock it off**".

This is *not* related to the question: *What are the origins for the phrases "Knock it off" and "Cut it out"?* I am enquiring about the connection  between two distinct idioms, one being:

*To have a chip on one's shoulder*

The other being:

*Knock it off*

It looks to me like they might both originate from the same source!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the origins for the phrases "Knock it off" and "Cut it out"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96696/191178)

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is if  you have something on your shoulder, I could knock it off. But that is not the idiom for Stop it!: Knock it off. So, no connection.

Comment: @Laurel That question's answer says "knock it off" dates to 1834, but the asker just found a usage of it from 1830.

Comment: The 1830 references are a literal use of "knock it off" not the metaphorical one - I'm sure people were talking about knocking things off other things well before then (in 17th century or before), but it's unconnected with the metaphorical meaning "stop it".

Comment: It doesn't help that the approved answer to the other question only gives a partial account of the origin of "knock it off", which may be partly connected to auctioneers but probably relates to the earlier idiom "knock off" meaning "do quickly, finish quickly" which the OED has at 1817, or the (originally 17th century) sense "to leave off one's work" (still used in the UK in phrases like "knock off for the day").

Comment: Closely related: [What semantic notions underlie the 19th-century US challenge to knock a chip of wood off someone's shoulder?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541626/what-semantic-notions-underlie-chip-on-your-shoulder-with-the-19th-us-challeng)